# Swift 5.7's Regex Builder for email validation

Tags: swift, swift-regexbuilder

I have the following reg ex pattern to validate the email address with max length of 100 characters: `(?=^.{0,100}$)([A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$)`

I'm struggling to convert this pattern to the Swift 5.7's Regex builder DSL syntax, I I couldn't find a clue for how to convert it the correct way, however, the option in Xcode editor: (select the string pattern -> right-click -> Refactor -> Convert to Regex Builder) is disabled for no obvious reason.

Comment: Don't validate emails with Regex. It's actually really complicated, and you're practically guaranteed to get it wrong. https://davidcel.is/articles/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: @Alexander yeah you're right .. I've found a better way to validate emails in Swift: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/validating-email-addresses/

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make it regex by surrounding it with `/` like:

```
let regex = /(?=^.{0,100}$)([A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$)/
```

Then you can use the Xcode's refactor feature to convert it to regex builder with one click:

[image: Demo]

```
let regex = Regex {
    Lookahead {
        Regex {
            /^/
            Repeat(0...100) {
                /./
            }
            /$/
        }
    }
    Capture {
        Regex {
            OneOrMore {
                CharacterClass(
                    .anyOf("._%+-"),
                    ("A"..."Z"),
                    ("0"..."9"),
                    ("a"..."z")
                )
            }
            "@"
            OneOrMore {
                CharacterClass(
                    .anyOf(".-"),
                    ("A"..."Z"),
                    ("a"..."z"),
                    ("0"..."9")
                )
            }
            "\\"
            /./
            Repeat(2...4) {
                CharacterClass(
                    ("A"..."Z"),
                    ("a"..."z")
                )
            }
            /$/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I generated the `Regex` builder using the way you posted in the answer, but the generated builder pattern (which looks exactly like the above one) doesn't match valid email addresses,  but if I use the original pattern string in the init of `Regex` it works well, so I guess this feature in XCode is buggy (Refactor -> Convert to Regex Builder)